# Why my string looping in this while?

Tags: c, while-loop

I am checking carNo in the loop so I request the user input.
But string "Enter carBrand and carPrice:" is looping in console. Don't understand why.

```
//manually fill records

filePtr = fopen("CARDATABASE.dat", "rb+");
printf("Enter car no: ");
scanf("%d", &blankEntry.carNo);

while (blankEntry.carNo!=0){

    printf("Enter carBrand and carPrice: \n");
    fscanf(stdin, "%d %s %f", &blankEntry.carNo, blankEntry.carBrand, &blankEntry.carPrice);
    fseek(filePtr, (blankEntry.carNo - 1)*sizeof(struct carData), SEEK_SET);
    fwrite(&blankEntry, sizeof(struct carData), 1, filePtr);        
    printf("Enter car no: ");
    scanf("%d",&blankEntry.carNo);

}
```

Comment: You need to test the return value of `scanf()`. If it isn't the number of assignments requested there was something wrong wit the input. `if (fscanf(stdin, "%d%s%f", &blankEntry.carNo, blankEntry.carBrand, &blankEntry.carPrice) != 3) /* error */;`

Comment: Add an `&` before `blankEntry.carBrand` in `fscanf`

Comment: It did not work. carBrand is a char array indeed. I don't think it needs & operator like integers.

Comment: Maybe when I press enter after inputting carBrand and carPrice, \n becomes the input to new carNo?

Comment: OMG I found the mistake. In fscanf I should only take carBrand and carPrice input. Instead I also took carNo twice. I deleted it and now it works.